# Can you tell yast that you've installed a source tarball

Tags: opensuse

Is there a way to tell YAST the opensuse package manager that you've installed a source tarball for a package that is listed with dependencies?  I wanted to install emacs from source with --with-x-toolkit=lucid enabled so I could lose the error message I get every time I open a new client in server mode.  Now I need to tell YAST that the package is installed so that I can maintain the dependency tree etc.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution would be to create an rpm of your modified package and install that RPM. That's quite easy using the Open Build Service, an automated package building and collaboration platform used by the openSUSE project to build their distribution.

Your workflow is:

Create Account

Branch the original package to your home repo (like in github)

Change the spec file build options

check in the changes to OBS

Wait for the package to build

Download

Install using zypper or yast

It takes about 5 minutes and you have your custom emacs build installed and fully known to the rpm/yast/zypper tool stack

https://build.opensuse.org